# Массовый UPDATE в MySQL для нескольких условий

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь реализовать массовый UPDATE, но не могу понять как его сделать для нескольких условий. Сейчас данный запрос выполняется в цикле.

```
UPDATE product_tara_test 
SET price = ?, date_import = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) 
WHERE id_product = ? AND id_stockroom = ?
```

Т.к. на каждую итерацию происходит запрос, время выполнения скрипта существенно торомзит из-за этого. 
Пытаюсь реализовать через **CASE** Собрав динамически запрос, но не могу понять как его сделать по нескольким условиям:
 **WHERE id_product = ? AND id_stockroom = ?**

```
UPDATE `product_tara_test` SET price = CASE
WHEN id_product = 1 THEN 100
...
END,
date_import = CASE
WHEN id = 1 THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) 
....
END,
WHERE id_product  in (1,2,3....) AND  id_stockroom IN (1, 1, 1....)
```

Comment: Можно попробовать не каждый запрос выполнять в цикле, а забить в цикле транзакцию и разово выполнить.

Comment: Я бы предложил сначала весь массив ***(price, id_product, id_stockroom)*** загнать во временную таблицу на *Memory Engine*, а потом одним запросом обновить... а полю ***date_import*** присвоить `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` и вообще убрать его из запроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE product_tara_test P
  JOIN (
        select ? as id_product, ? as id_stockroom, ? as price
        union all
        select ? as id_product, ? as id_stockroom, ? as price
        ...
       ) D
     ON P.id_product=D.id_product and P.id_stockroom=D.id_stockroom
    SET price=D.price, date_import = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```