# Массовый update в mysql в один запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть проблема. У меня в цикле идет обновление 30к+ строк. И тратится на это 40+ минут.
То есть у меня в цикле выполняется такой запрос:

```
UPDATE product 
     SET price = $product['price'],
         price_retail = $product['price_retail'] 
WHERE upc = $product['supplier'] AND sku = $product['uniqCode']
```

И так происходит 30 тыс раз.
Как можно это сделать в один запрос? Я видел примеры с Update ... case.. when... но так и не смог понять, как это применить в моем случае.

---

Изначально данные приходят в разных форматах. Я скачиваю файлы от разных поставщиков и привожу их в единый формат(xls), с которым я работаю.
Вот пример:

> Поставщик Уникальный код  Оптовая цена    Розничная цена  Остаток на складе
>
> Apple      ABC123            763$          1171$             5

В нем 30-70 тыс строк(Для каждого поставщика, а их 8+). В файле есть 2 поля(помимо полей с ценами), по которым я определяю товар в базе данных, это supplier(поставщик) и uniqCode(Уникальный код).
Мне нужно именно ОБНОВИТЬ товар, а если его нету в базе, то вставлять не нужно(потому insert with no dublicate не подходит).

Comment: А откуда в php эти данные? Не из той же базы, случаем?

Comment: Индекс (upc, sku) может помочь; Если sku уникальный для продукта, зачем второе условие?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Забыл указать. Добавил в описание. Данные с xls.
sku может быть похожее с другими товарами. Тут важен supplier(upc) тоже.

Comment: В цикле какого языка у вас идет обновление ? похоже на php... Если вы подставляете значения именно так, как тут написали, то конечно это медленно, потому что БД приходится тратить время на компиляцию каждого запроса. Если же использовать возможности привяки переменных вашего драйвера работы с БД (практически во всех языках такое есть) то будет гораздо быстрее. т.е. перед циклом у вас должно быть что то вроде `prepare('update ... set X=?, Y=? where X=? and Z=?')`, а внутри цикла только execute с передачей параметров в запрос или с предварительными bind_value

Comment: хотя конечно можно пойти и по такому пути https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664901/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-update-%D0%B2-mysql-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9/664913#664913

Answer (score 0):

1. Если у вас известен id product, лучше по нему строить where и соответветственно индекс должен быть.
2. Можно обновлять записи в транзакции, к примеру по 1000 шт.
3. Из кода не очень понятно `$product['supplier']` и `$product['uniqCode']` всегда разные. Побольше бы информации.

Comment: 3. Важнее, что разные price/price_retail

Comment: Добавил в описании. id product нету.
$product['supplier'](поставщик) всегда(для одного файл, который я паршу один), а  $product['uniqCode'] не повторяется.
Но чтобы не было дублей в базе данных, для проверки я использую проверку по поставщику(supplier) и уникальному коду(uniqCode), потому что другие поставщики, могут дать такой же UniqCode

Answer (score 0):

> Я видел примеры с Update ... case.. when... но так и не смог понять, как это применить в моем случае

```
UPDATE product SET
  price = CASE
    WHEN upc = 'Apple' AND sku = 'ABC123' THEN 763
    WHEN upc = … AND sku = … THEN … -- по одной строке на каждую строку из xls
    …
    ELSE price END, -- не забываем про ELSE, чтоб не затереть то, чего нет в файле.
  price_retail = CASE
    WHEN upc = 'Apple' AND sku = 'ABC123' THEN 1171
    WHEN upc = … AND sku = … THEN … -- по одной строке на каждую строку из xls
    …
    ELSE price_retail END -- не забываем про ELSE, чтоб не затереть то, чего нет в файле.
```

строки `WHEN … THEN …` можно собрать в самом xls-файле формулам на основе значений в ячейках.

У самого sql-сервера или среды исполнения запросов может быть ограничение как на количество символов в запросе, так и на количество веток у CASE. Возможно, придётся дробить запрос на части.