# Запрос на Update таблицы массивом объектов с разными полями

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, например со следующими полями:
`test_table: id | key1 | key2 | key3`

Есть массив который нужно внести в таблицу:

```
array [
    0 = {id: 1, key1: "some_value"},
    1 = {id: 3, key2: "some_value", key3: "some_value"}
]
```

То есть каждый элемент массива содержит id и набор из полей таблицы - не обязательно полный, и не обязательно такой же, как в других элементах этого массива.

Возможно ли одним запросом обновить данные таблицы данными из всего массива? Или проще и правильнее записать каждый элемент по отдельности (в цикле)?
Если возможно всё сразу, то как должен выглядеть такой SQL-запрос?

Comment: В цикле надо не таблицу менять, а строить динамически sql запрос который проведет нужный update. Для начала из этого массива построить другой (массив/объект/словарь или как в вашем языке это принято) вида {key1: "some_value", key2: '...', key3: '...'} и сделать универсальную функцию, которая получив такой массив строит на основе него update .... set key1=x, key2=... из всех ключей массива что есть

Comment: @Mike Динамический запрос это понятно, но как такой запрос тогда должен выглядеть? Несколько UPDATE в одном запросе с несколькими WHERE id=X, или есть более красивые конструкции?

Comment: Я бы по одной записи за раз апдейтил. Оно достаточно быстро, не вижу смысла делать какие то хитроумные конструкции на подобии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664901/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-update-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9/664913#664913  Но возможно было бы правильнее сначала узнать, а требуется ли вообще update, если ситуация что данные в БД уже совпадают с данными в массиве частая